# How to use pun in this story

Tags: style, character-development, humor

I wrote:

> A funny thing happened to me recently, which I would like to share with you.
>
> First, let me say the private English school I'm studying at is called SPEAK UP. 
>   A couple of days ago, one of our teachers invited us to a pub quiz. You may ask "what is a pub quiz?". Well, a pub quiz is held in a pub or bar. The participants split into teams, and a person, called quizmaster, asks them questions. The quiz consists of several rounds. Each team is supposed to write their answers on a paper and match them with the other teams at the end of each round. They are awarded some points for the correct answers.
>
> Anyways, I was late, so when I got to the pub, the students had already settled down and the teacher was asking one of the students a question. I approached the teacher from the back and said 'hello' to everybody. The teacher stopped reading, turned back and started looking at me in amusement.
>
> "I'm Roger" - I said because not everybody knew me. A girl asked out loud: "Are you going to speak up?". I quickly responded: "Yes, I go". The girl, without paying any attention to me, repeated "Are you going to finish the question?". Oh! I then realized she was talking to the teacher all this time. (Such audacity!)
>
> You know, I felt quite embarrassed, but I kept a poker face and just joined one of the teams to play the quiz with them.

There is a pun in this story. I want to convey the pun in an indirect way, so that the reader finds it by own self and laughs at it. Again, I want to make it certain the reader will get the pun.

Moreover, the girl's questions are just too rude and they might seem unbelievable to the reader. How can I work on that part?

Please guide me to make the writing smooth, succinct, laughable and believable.

Comment: This is quite firmly off-topic here; have placed on hold.

Comment: @neilfein then what is the story tag for? I never knew what is this site for.

Comment: My main question is about the proper usage of pun here the other requests are not necessary.

Comment: Is this story originally told in another language?